# How to safely remove the active task in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs

I have a NodeJS + Angular 5 Application, build by Code Fresh and deploy on AWS platform S3, ECS, ECR, EC2, and load balancers.

[image]

I noticed, I have a lot of active task running in my

**Task Definition Name : api**

I want to do some clean up of my AWS account.

[image]

Is it okay if I remove the rest of the task except the `68` one ?

How do I check if the rest is not being use ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not removing those. They aren't 'active tasks' as you mentioned, but rather revisions of a single Task Definition, which is a configuration for how a Service will run a task (defines Container details, resource allocation .etc).

Those revisions you're looking at are similar to 'commits' or even 'branches' if you're familiar Git, but not for an entire codebase, only like 100 lines of JSON. You're using a 3rd party deployment automation tool (CodeFresh), which may depend on those revisions for roll-back procedures or at least expect them to be there. Probably doesn't but I'd err on the side of caution.

Task Definitions don't consume any resources and take up virtually no storage (AWS doesn't even charge for them. If you want to see *actual* 'running tasks'

1. click on Clusters
2. select any Cluster that has more than zero 'active tasks'
3. Then you'll see a list of services with the number of 'desired' and 'running' tasks and I'm sure you can figure the rest out from there by clicking around.

A little side story to give to context for my caution in this area... I did a 'clean up' in my AWS account the other night right before bed. I deleted an ECS Cluster that had no active Services running on it; first cluster I ever made.

1 minute later 20 websites/apps crash, that entire accounts infrastructure. Little did I realize I had created that cluster through the 'setup wizard', which spun up an entire VCP, ELB and all the underlying resources with a CloudFormaton Template. I had at some point started using that VPC and related resources as the home form my new Clusters.

Upon deletion of the Cluster it rolled-back my CloudFormation Stack deleting... well enough underlying network resources to crash everything.

Task Definitions, are pretty insignificant disposable things, but thats what I thought about my empty Cluster. Moral of the story...

1. use 'Delete Portection' whenever possible
2. If you didn't make it (all of it) don't delete it without doing your research.

If I were you I would direct this question to CodeFresh support/forum to be sure. In the mean time those Task Definitions cost you nothing and you  should rarely even need to enter that UI/view you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove the task definations safely.

When you deregister a task definition, it is immediately marked as INACTIVE. Existing tasks and services that reference an INACTIVE task definition continue to run without disruption, and existing services that reference an INACTIVE task definition can still scale up or down by modifying the service's desired count. [Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deregister-task-definition.html)

**To check the task which are in being use:**

1. Go to ECS cluster.
2. Select your cluster.
3. Inside selected cluster, select task.
4. You can see all your running task with respective task definition that they are using.

[image: ECS cluster]

Except the task definition that you see in above procedure you can deregister rest of the task definitions.

**To deregister a task definition:**

1. Open the Amazon ECS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/.
2. From the navigation bar, choose the region that contains your task definition.
3. In the navigation pane, choose Task Definitions.
4. On the Task Definitions page, choose the task definition name that contains one or more revisions that you want to deregister.
5. On the Task Definition Name page, select the box to the left of each task definition revision you want to deregister.
6. Choose Actions, Deregister.

[image]